# Working on Binary Data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, binary

I have loaded a text file test file in matlab. The load function has now created a variable `test` with values

```
1 2  3  4   5
2 3 NaN NaN NaN
```

Now I have a initialized variable `X = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]` and `Y = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`.
I want `X` to read the first row of `test` variable and corresponding to the number it reads change its value of the element from `0` to `1`. Suppose it reads `1`, it should change its element `X(1)` from `0` to `1`. Similarly `Y` should do the same wrt second row of `test`.

Any idea how should I proceed?

Comment: your question is unclear and you should provide more information. What do you mean by "I want X to read the first row"? What's the condition for changing from `0` to `1`? Do you change if it's positive or non-zero or what?

Comment: Consider the "1,2,3,4,5" are indexes for the sports i like. So in the vector X I want to change the values of my elements (1,2,3,4,5) from "0 to 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index directly into a vector like so:

```
x=zeros(1,10);%# your zero vector
a=[1,3,7,8];  %# the index of sports you like
x(a)=1        %# change from 0 to 1

x =

     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
```

Going by your comment, I think this is what you want.